# MS SQL Query (How to Subtract to two columns in different tables)

Tags: sql, join, subtraction

Hi i have two tables which is tblPOdetails and tblPDdetails

tblPOdetails

```
PONumber  -   Item  -   Qty  -   Price        
12345---------soap------5-------4.50
```

tblPDdetails

```
PONumber  -   Item  -   Qty  -   Price        
12345---------soap------4-------4.50
```

Result I Want

```
PONumber  -   Item  -   Qty  -   Price        
12345---------soap------1-------4.50
```

all the columns and fields in that table is same.

Now i want to subtract tblpodetails.qty - tblpddetails.qty where PONumber = '12345' i want to get the result of that scenario can anyone teach me the script.

Thank you!

Comment: slightly off topic , people who don't have access to sql currently can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `PONumber` is your table key in both tables, this query should give you your required result:

```
SELECT tblPOdetails.PONumber AS PONumber,
       tblPOdetails.Item AS Item,
       (tblPOdetails.Qty - tblPDdetails.Qty) AS Qty,
       tblPOdetails.Price AS Price
    FROM tblPOdetails
    JOIN tblPDdetails ON tblPOdetails.PONumber = tblPDdetails.PONumber
    WHERE tblPOdetails.PONumber = 12345
```

Edit: Added table name to PONumber.

Edit2: Replaced `USING` with `ON`. Thanks for the tip Hart CO!

Comment: PONumber is in both tables.

Comment: It should be fine since it is the field I am using for the JOIN, right?

Comment: Well, added the table name to the field `PONumber`. Still not sure whether it actually has to be specified or if it is optional. Anyone?

Comment: This will throw an error in SQL Server, `USING()` is not supported, need to use `ON` for `JOIN` criteria.  Regarding table names, table aliases are preferred, but only required when there is field ambiguity between the tables you are joining.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal The error occurs only because you used `ON` instead of `USING`. With `USING` it actually works for MySQL after fixing the errors: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dc63/5

Comment: @HartCO Thanks for the tip, did not know MS SQL does not know the `USING` syntax.

Comment: I didn't knew about USING() , have been using ON with joins. But then I do not deal with DBs that much.

Comment: Hi @AbhinavGauniyal i tried this one but it's not working... ERROR : ponumber is not a recognized table hints option.

Comment: Any more details on this error? Did you try the exact and most current code from the answer?

Comment: @TimoSta i tried using the exact code you provide..but it give me redundant result.. meaning if i have 2 same PONumber in PDdetails and POdetails the result give 4 rows... and two of them is redundant.

Comment: Well, yes, it does, but if you do have duplicate `PONumber`s, this field is not a key field anymore. Then you also cannot simply do the calculation anymore -- which one of the entries should be used for the calculation if they have different values?

Comment: @TimoSta thank you... is there a way to achieve my  requirement?

Comment: Yes, but you first have to define your requirements. Have a look at the question in my last comment.

Comment: @TimoSta  i need the difference of the Qty fields.

Comment: If there are multiple entries per table with the same `PONumber`, there are multiple ways to calculate the difference of the `Qty` fields.

Answer (score -1):

```
select tblPOdetails.PONumber,
tblPOdetails.item,
tblPOdetails.qty - tblPDdetails.qty AS qty,
tblPOdetails.price
from tblPOdetails 
inner join tblPDdetails on tblPOdetails.PONumber = tblPDdetails.PONumber
where tblPOdetails.PONumber = 12345
```

Comment: I don't think this will produce desired output , see your select statement.

Comment: @bryangm  the PONumber is not my primary key...if i have two same ponumber in podetails and in pddetails the result  it give me 4 rows result which is recurring.

Comment: @Daryl you probably need to include further details in your question then, such as any primary key/foreign key relationships or what combination of fields in either table will make the rows unique